# How can I implement a Apple License Subscription in Flutter per Bluetooth connected unique Device (Car Vehicle Identification Number)

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I did create a Flutter app that connects to Cars over Bluetooth.
Each car can be identified with a Vehicle Identification Number (VIN).
I would like to be able to have a renewable subscription per car identified.
Reading the Apple description it seems like there is no handling for keying the VIN (Unique Bluetooth) to the subscription. I also have to handle the refund case gracefully.

I am using the flutter [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase)
If I use consumables then I lose the ability to auto-renew and I have to track the expiration in my database.

Do I miss something here? Any insides to cover my case?

Comment: A user can only subscribe to an auto renewing subscription once. You could have subscription tiers in your subscription group (1 car, 2 cars, 5 cars etc). Your app needs to track how many unique vehicles it is registered with compared to the subscription level. You will also need some way of synchronising the registered VINs between the user devices since the user can access their subscription on all of their devices. Without sync they could have 3 devices connected to 3 different cars and all using the 1 car subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the info, how if someone has already one car subscribed does that mean I select the 2 car sub. because I kept track of it in the db but I would charge only for one car again because the first sub. stays active. I have a shared db so that would not be a problem.